# HTML CSS Modal content is "out of box"

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

```
.modal-body {
    height:100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

<div id="modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" style="width:80%;height:100%">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content" style="width:80%;height:100%">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">ABC </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" id="abcmodal" style="display:inline-block"style="height:auto;">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer" style="display:none;">
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Everything works fine , but when the content is too "long" , the content will out of place.

> Screenshot : https://prnt.sc/sre2vw

any idea what should i edit ?

Comment: Can you give some more CSS and/or HTML to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: @John, unless you can replicate this inside a runnable snippet (https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) we cant really help you with this.

Comment: @DanielBrose I think you meant to @ greenboxgoolu, not me.

Comment: lol, i meant to say as @John mentioned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your code and it is working fine. I put a long paragraph in the modal-body, the content was shown properly with scrolling. Please run the code snippet for the result.

```css
.modal-body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<div id="modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" style="width:80%;height:100%">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content" style="width:80%;height:100%">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">ABC </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" id="abcmodal" style="display:inline-block" style="height:auto;">
        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae
          est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis
          tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan
          porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae
          est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis
          tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan
          porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae
          est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis
          tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan
          porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer" style="display:none;">
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```